# How to Calculate the Variance of the Aggregate of a Bernoulli Process Given Known False Positive and False Negative Rates

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, measurement-error

I have $n$ sensors which output either $0$ or $1$. These sensors have known measurement error reflected by a false positive rate, $fpr$ and false negative rate, $fnr$. In my case, $fnr > fpr$.

Given measurements from the sensors $s_i$ where $s_i$ is $0$ or $1$ for sensor $i$, I'm interested in calculating the expected sum or mean of the sensors at any given time with a margin of error/confidence interval (by using the standard deviation).

I was able to derive the expected mean of the sensors as follows:

$E[mean] = {(\sum_{i=1}^{n} s_i) - n * fpr \over{n*(1 - fnr - fpr)}}$

I simulated my situation and this formula matches the results. But I can't find a formula for the standard deviation that matches my empirical results from the simulation.

I expect that the standard deviation of the mean should decrease with respect to the number of sensors I have while increasing with respect to the mean since $fnr > fpr$. The intuition being that a) larger numbers of sensors lowers the error of the mean and b) a greater false negative rate will increase the errors as the actual number of 1s increases.

Here is a graph of the standard deviation vs. the true mean (as a %) for different values of $n$:

[image]

I've tried modeling the variance (and thus the standard deviation) as a sum of the variances of a binomial distribution and as a multinomial distribution with four outcomes: true positive, false positive, true negative and false negative. But I haven't been able to get any formulas to match the results from the simulation.

How can I derive the formula for the variance?

Comment: In your binomial model, what are you using for the success probability?